# Duplicate Dynamic Select Box using Angular 6+ Form Array

Tags: drop-down-menu, angular-material, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

Select Box 1 is "**Path**".
Select Box 2 is "**SkillSet**".

I'm trying to duplicate group of select boxes(Path and SkillSet) based on a button click. So when I click Add button the select box(Path and SkillSet) form element will be duplicated. The catch here is the select box "Skillset" element's options are dynamic because its depends on the select box "Path".

**Issue Below:**
**Step1**: Choosing Path as BackEnd and Skill will be populated based on the Path. In the second select box selected as Java8.

[image]

**Step2**: Clicking Add button, so the select box Path and Skill is duplicated. Now choosing select box Path as FrontEnd.

[image]

**Step3**: After choosing Path as FrontEnd in the second row, the selected Skill in first row's are reseted to empty. (In the image I have added two Path's)

[image]

**StackBlitz Demo for the Issue:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-duplicate-dynamic-select-box?file=null

Expectation is : I have to select each Path and respective Skill. Like If I choose 3 different path, then I have to choose 3 different skills in the 3 different row of select boxes.

I have tried many solutions. Nothing is working out. Can someone help in this case.?

Sorry for my English and bad formatting. Appreciate your help !!!

Comment: As I'm not well versed with adding new project to stackblitz, I've added the entire .ts and html code **with some modifications** in the answer section. Have a look at it. *Hope this fulfills your expectation*.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. It worked like charm. This is the stackblitz URL which contains the fix.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zwhq1r

Comment: Do mark the answer as accepted so that someone else ma find it useful while searching :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Push the skillsets for the selected path into an array and access them in the HTML file using the index.

**In .ts File**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormArray, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  skillSetObj;
  majorPathObj;

  skillForm: FormGroup;
  skillList: FormArray;

  choosenPath;
  skillsForSelectedPath:any = [];  // <--- Declare a new array for the skillsets to be pushed

  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.skillSetObj = {
      "BackEnd": ["Java8", "Node JS", "Python", "Dotnet"],
      "FrontEnd": ["Javascript ", "Angular ", "React", "Vue"],
      "Database": ["Oracle", "Postgres", "Mysql"]
    };

    this.majorPathObj = ["BackEnd", "FrontEnd", "Database"];

    this.skillForm = this.fb.group({
      skillFormArray: this.fb.array([this.createSkills()])
    });

    this.skillList = this.skillForm.get('skillFormArray') as FormArray;
  }

  createSkills(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      majorPath: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      skillSet: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
    });
  }

  getSkillFormGroup(index): FormGroup {
    const formGroup = this.skillList.controls[index] as FormGroup;
    return formGroup;
  }

  get skillFormGroup() {
    return this.skillForm.get('skillFormArray') as FormArray;
  }

  addNewSkill() {
    this.skillList.push(this.createSkills());
  }

  removeSkill(skillRowIndex) {
    this.skillList.removeAt(skillRowIndex);
  }

  prepareSkillSet(event, i) {
    this.skillsForSelectedPath[i]=this.skillSetObj[event.value];  // <--- Push the skills for the selected majorPath into the new array
    const formGroup = this.getSkillFormGroup(i);
    const choosenPath = formGroup.controls['majorPath'].value;
    this.choosenPath = choosenPath;
  }
```

}

** In HTML file **

```
<form [formGroup]="skillForm">

  <div formArrayName="skillFormArray">
      <div *ngFor="let skillArray of skillFormGroup.controls; let i=index">
          <div [formGroupName]="i">
              <div >
                  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                      <mat-select formControlName="majorPath"
                          (selectionChange)="prepareSkillSet($event, i)">
                          <mat-option *ngFor="let major of majorPathObj" value={{major}}>
                              {{major}}
                          </mat-option>
                      </mat-select>
                  </mat-form-field>
                  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                    <mat-select formControlName="skillSet">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let skill of skillsForSelectedPath[i]" [value]="skill">   <!-- display the skills for the selected majorPath using the index of the newly created variable -->
                            {{skill}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
                  <button *ngIf="i===0" mat-fab color="accent" class="add-file-button mt-5"
                      (click)="addNewSkill()" aria-label="Add Skill">
                      <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
                  </button>
                  <button *ngIf="i!==0" mat-fab color="warn" class="add-file-button"
                      (click)="removeSkill(i)" aria-label="Remove Skill">
                      <mat-icon>remove</mat-icon>
                  </button>
              </div>

          </div>

      </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

So everytime the *majorPath* is the skills object is also updated and you can select the corresponding skills for the newly selected *majorPath*.

**The output looks like below**

[image]